# Get SQL Distinct Row Without NULL Values

Tags: sql, text, null, amazon-redshift, distinct

I'm trying to get a distinct row using SQL from set of records that have matching key/id value, but NULLs in different columns. Hard to explain so please see screenshot. Any ideas?

[image]

```
create temporary table my_table (
    id varchar(30), segmentdate1 date, converted1 varchar(10), segmentdate2 date, converted2 varchar(10)
);

insert into my_table (
    id, segmentdate1, converted1, segmentdate2, converted2
)
values
    ('Michael','9/15/2020','No',NULL,NULL),
    ('Michael',NULL,NULL,'7/1/2019','Yes')
;
```

Comment: Hi, when you are doing the select, do you do it like this : select distinct id, segmentdate, converted,... from your_table ? If yes, then you will get the result as you are getting. The distinct keyword is applying to all the columns. Can you share with us a query you are trying to execute ? Thanks!

Comment: Is this from a single table?  Or instead are you showing us the output from a join?

Comment: I've tried distinct and group by and neither work. And, this is a result from a more complex query, but I wanted to keep it simple

Comment: From a single table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select id, max(segmentdate1) as segmentdate1, max(converted1) as converted1,
       max(segmentdate2) as segmentdate2, max(converted2) as converted2
from t
group by id;
```

Note:  I made up names for the columns so they are unique.

This is probably a result set created from another query.  That query probably has the wrong `group by` keys.  You should probably fix that query.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @my_table table (
    id varchar(30), segmentdate1 date, converted1 varchar(10), segmentdate2 date, converted2 varchar(10)
);

insert into @my_table (
    id, segmentdate1, converted1, segmentdate2, converted2
)
values
    ('Michael','9/15/2020','No',NULL,NULL),
    ('Michael',NULL,NULL,'7/1/2019','Yes')
;

select id,max(isnull(segmentdate1,'1200-01-01')) segmentdate2
    ,max(isnull(converted1,'')) converted1, max(isnull(segmentdate2,'1200-01-01')) segmentdate2
    ,max(isnull(converted2,'')) converted2
from @my_table
group by id
```